# Creating a Yearly Auto-Renewal Plan with Region-Based Pricing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm looking to implement a yearly auto-renewal plan with different pricing based on regions. Specifically, I want to set the plan price at $13.49 for the US & Canada as well as Europe, and $8.99 for other regions. I've explored App Store Connect, but it seems there's no direct option to configure this. The only available method seems to be setting prices for individual countries.

If anyone has experience with this and can provide guidance or steps on how to achieve region-based pricing for a yearly auto-renewal plan, I'd greatly appreciate it!

I have changed the Price of the first country of Africa, Middle East, and India region but not affect all countries in the selected region. [image: Here is the attached screenshot.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set the price for all regions to the cheaper price and then change the US and Canada to the higher price tier?

Comment: It is a good idea to set cheaper prices for all regions and then change for the US and Canada but I also include the same price tier for the Europe region. There is 42 country inside the European region and it is challenging to change the 42-country price.